# Should I do z score normalization after quantile normalization?

Tags: normalization

Quantile normalization helps in making distribution comparable but the values are not intuitive enough to set easy cut-off. Using z score we can easily understand and set cut-off like z score > 2. Can anyone comment on this, if I am doing something wrong in transforming data twice ?

Comment: I don't understand the situation you are asking about. Can you say more?

Comment: I have samples as columns and probes as rows. First I am doing quantile normalization : overlaying density plot of probe values of any sample will look similar to other samples. After that, I can calculate z score for probes for any samples. Did it clarify?